# ag-Grid Disable Horizontal FillHandle

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, direction

Is it possible to disable the javascript Ag-Grid fill handle horizontally ?

I see it is possible to get the fill direction from utilising the fillOperation function, but there is nothing in the docs about disabling a horizontal fill.

In the examples on the Fill Handle info page on below link you can fill the name across all columns which would be incorrect.

[image]

Is it best then to use the fillOperation function and just not copy anything unless the direction is up/down?

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection-fill-handle/

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same requirement.

Comment: I didn't find a way to disable it no. As a work around in our example we are using some dropdown menus so I was able to use [valueSetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-setters/) to validate for those cells, but text only cells are still horizontally filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Version 24.0.0, you can use the `fillHandleDirection` property in gridOptions and set it to `y`.

You can do "x", "y" or "xy" and also there is a function to change it on the fly

```
gridOptions.api.setFillHandleDirection(direction);
```

This is all available in the ag grid docs

[AG-Grid Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection-fill-handle)

Comment: I didn't see that update yet, gridOptions.api.fillHandleDirection(direction) works, thanks !